# Dimension of Lie algebra and Lie group

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $E$ be a finite banach space, and let the Lie-algebra $$E\oplus[E,E]\oplus[E,[E,E]]\oplus....$$
be the formal Lie-series $L$.

So the space of formal-Lie-series $L$ can be seen as the completion of the free Lie-algebra over $E$ $L_x$ and hence is finite dimensional. By Lie's third theorem, one can associate to $L$ a Lie-group $G$.

> Now my question is, how does the dimension of $G$ relate to the dimension of $L$. Is there some known correspondence between the dimension between the both. Does $G$ even have to be finite dimensional?

Best wishes

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Shaun In my opinion, I provided enough context, I have stated what I know and what is missing.  A statement of an exercise would be "Let $L$ be the space of formal Lie series, proof that there exists an Lie group associated with L and find its dimension".